# Does codegolf involve only code size?

Tags: support, tags

I'd like to know if codegolf does allow other kinds of challenges, like memory-size related ones (Given a structure, try to use the least amount of bits to store the same information) and so on. I don't know if this kind of challenge fits codegolfing or not.

Comment: If you have an idea for a challenge, you can post it in the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to get feedback on how to ensure it's a good fit for the site.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are two different usages of "code golf" here:

The tag [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is applied to challenges which involve competing to produce the shortest valid source code. More details and a list of challenges can be found by clicking on the tag name.

This website, "codegolf.stackexchange.com", has the full name [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/). This site has several different challenge types, code golf being just one of them.

For example:

- [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code)
- [programming-puzzle](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/programming-puzzle)
- [king-of-the-hill](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/king-of-the-hill)
- [cops-and-robbers](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cops-and-robbers)

Sometimes people post challenges that have their own scoring method that does not fit exactly into one of these categories. These are tagged [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge), and the challenge post contains a detailed description of how submissions will be scored.

We also have non-challenge questions, asking for advice on solving such challenges. These are tagged [tips](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tips).

Answer (score 1):

**From the [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) tag wiki:**

> Code-golf is a competition to solve a particular problem in the fewest bytes of source code. If you want to score by characters instead of bytes, state this explicitly in the challenge. If source code length is not the primary scoring criterion, consider using another tag instead.

So, no, code golf is solely about code length.

Comment: I don't think OP meant [tag:code-golf] instead of CodeGolf.SE

Answer (score 0):

### No

[code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-golf) is only about the shortest code in any language. Other challenges are tagged [code-challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-challenge).

Comment: I see, thanks. Do challenges like the one i described already exists? inside or outside of stackexchange, i don't see a tag related to my interest.

Comment: @Agggg There is [tag:fastest-code] for the fastest code possible, but for 'memory golf', tag your challenge as [tag:code-challenge] and describe the winning criteria (here, the least memory used by a program)

Comment: @Agggg The craziest of all: [tag:code-bowling] is about the longest code possible.